# Merging multiple case (in match/case) in Scala

Tags: scala, controls

I have the code that `instance.get` returns value, and based on the type I process accordingly.

```
  instance.get match {
    case v:Range  => {
      val sizeInBytes = util.conversion.Util.getBytesForBits(v.size)
      val value = v.decode(contentByteArray.slice(index, index + sizeInBytes))
      index += sizeInBytes
      res(key) = value
    }
    case v:Encoding => {
      val sizeInBytes = util.conversion.Util.getBytesForBits(v.size)
      val value = v.decode(contentByteArray.slice(index, index + sizeInBytes))
      index += sizeInBytes
      res(key) = value
    }
    ...
  }
```

In the code, I have duplication for the `Range` and `Encoding` type. How can I merge the two cases?

I tried the `|` operator, but it doesn't work.

```
case v:Range | v:Encoding
```

Comment: Do you get an error? I did some research and I think this "variable binding in alternative pattern" kind of code might not be allowed by Scala. See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SUGGEST-25

Comment: Does `case v @ (Range | Encoding) => { ... }` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can't work, because `Range.size` and `Encoding.size` are two completely different methods despite the fact that they are named the same. And same is true for `Range.decode` and `Edncoding.decode`.

So, when you write `v.size`, the type of `v` has to be known, it has to be either `v:Encoding` or `v:Range`, not `v:Encoding|v:Range`.

How to fix this? Make a common trait like this:

```
 trait SomethingWithDecodeAndSize {
   def size: Int
   def decode(bytes: Array[Byte]): Whatever
 }
```

And then, change the definitions of `Range` and `Encoding`:

```
class Range extends SomethingWithDecodeAndSize { ... }
class Encoding extends SomethingWithDecodeAndSize { ... }
```

Now you can just do `case v: SomethingWithDecodeAndSize => ...` in your match clause.

Also ... Don't do `instance.get`, that's bad taste. Do instead

```
instance match { 
   Some(v: SomethingWithDecodeAndSize) => ...
}
```

**Update** 
If you cannot modify the definitions of the original classes, you can use an extractor:

```
object SomethingWithDecodeAndSize {
   def unapply(a: Any): Option[SomethingWithDecodeAndSize] = a match {
      case r: Range => Some(new SomethingWithDecodeAndSize {
        def size = r.size
        def decode(bytes: Array[Byte]) = r.decode(bytes)
      })
      case r: Encoding => Some(new SomethingWithDecodeAndSize {
        def size = r.size
        def decode(bytes: Array[Byte]) = r.decode(bytes)
      })
      case _ => None
   }
 }
```

Now, you can do `case Some(SomethingWithDecodeAndSize(v)) => ...` in your match.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution to @Dima's in case you can't change definition of `Range` and `Encoding` (and there is no supertype with required methods):

```
trait RangeOrEncoding {
  def size: Int
  def decode(bytes: Array[Byte]): Whatever
}

implicit def liftRange(r: Range): RangeOrEncoding = new RangeOrEncoding {
  def size = r.size
  def decode(bytes: Array[Byte]) = r.decode(bytes)
}

// similar conversion for Encoding

// can also be a local def
private def handleRangeOrEncoding(v: RangeOrEncoding) = {
  val sizeInBytes = util.conversion.Util.getBytesForBits(v.size)
  val value = v.decode(contentByteArray.slice(index, index + sizeInBytes))
  index += sizeInBytes
  res(key) = value
}

instance match {
  case Some(v: Range) => handleRangeOrEncoding(v)
  case Some(v: Encoding) => handleRangeOrEncoding(v)
  ...
}
```

Comment: I would recommend an extractor rather than implicit in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I remember the cheerleaders in high school asking us, "How loose is your goose?"

```
scala> class C { def f(i: Int) = 2 * i }
defined class C

scala> class D { def f(i: Int) = 3 * i }
defined class D

scala> def test(x: Any) = x match { case y: { def f(i: Int): Int } => y.f(42) }
<console>:11: warning: a pattern match on a refinement type is unchecked
       def test(x: Any) = x match { case y: { def f(i: Int): Int } => y.f(42) }
                                            ^
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
test: (x: Any)Int

scala> test(new C)
res0: Int = 84

scala> test(new D)
res1: Int = 126

scala> test(42)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.f(int)
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
  at .reflMethod$Method1(<console>:11)
  at .test(<console>:11)
  ... 32 elided
```

I believe the answer was: "Loose, baby, loose."

Edit:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime._,universe._,language.reflectiveCalls
import reflect.runtime._
import universe._
import language.reflectiveCalls

scala> class C { def f(i: Int) = 2 * i }
defined class C

scala> class D { def f(i: Int) = 3 * i }
defined class D

scala> def f[A](a: A)(implicit tt: TypeTag[A]) = a match {
     | case b: { def f(i: Int): Int }
     | if tt.tpe <:< typeOf[{ def f(i: Int): Int }] =>
     |   b.f(42)
     | }
<console>:19: warning: a pattern match on a refinement type is unchecked
       case b: { def f(i: Int): Int }
               ^
f: [A](a: A)(implicit tt: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])Int

scala> f(new C)
res0: Int = 84

scala> f(new D)
res1: Int = 126

scala> f(3)    // now an ordinary MatchError
scala.MatchError: 3 (of class java.lang.Integer)
  at .f(<console>:18)
  ... 32 elided
```

So you can express it as an ordinary type bounds:

```
scala> def f[A <: { def f(i: Int): Int }](a: A) = a.f(42)
f: [A <: AnyRef{def f(i: Int): Int}](a: A)Int

scala> f(new C)
res3: Int = 84

scala> f(17)
<console>:20: error: inferred type arguments [Int] do not conform to method f's type parameter bounds [A <: AnyRef{def f(i: Int): Int}]
       f(17)
       ^
<console>:20: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(17)
 required: A
       f(17)
         ^
```

You still need to accept the cost of the reflective call, of course.

Comment: What about using type tags and `=:=`?

Comment: Don't ignore the warnings. They are important and meaningful. And explain exactly why you should not do what you are doing here.

Comment: @badcook Something like.

Comment: @Dima it may not be the OP's use case, but structural types are also meaningful.

Comment: @som-snytt not for pattern matching, they aren't. But even in other contexts beware of performance, and other subtle problems. There is almost always a better solution. And when I say "almost" I am being rather overcautious. ;)